# Javascript - checking if multiple fields are empty not working

Tags: javascript, html

HTML form look:

```
<form action="search" id="searchForm" onsubmit="return validateSearch()">
    <input type="text" name="byTitle" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" placeholder="Enter a word from title">
    <input type="text" name="byAuthor" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="First-name Last-name"> <!--  pattern="\w+ \w+" -->
    <input id="startDate" name="startDate" type="date">
    <input id="endDate" name="endDate" type="date">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javscript validating function:

```
function validateSearch() {

    var byTitle   = document.getElementById('searchForm').byTitle.value;
    // alert(byTitle);
    var byAuthor  = document.getElementById('searchForm').byAuthor.value;
    // alert(byAuthor);
    var startDate = document.getElementById('searchForm').startDate.value;
    //alert(startDate);
    var endDate   = document.getElementById('searchForm').endDate.value;
    //alert(endDate);       

    if(byTitle == byAuthor == startDate == endDate == ""){
        alert("Enter at least one search parameter!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, if I leave all form fields empty/unfilled and press submit, `alert("Enter at least one search parameter!");` message should pop-up, but it doesn't. Wanted to see what are the values of each field I have inserted `alert` after each field reading, and they are all same, empty string/blank. So, why is then that `if condition` not seeing them as same, empty fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is here:

**wrong**

```
if(byTitle == byAuthor == startDate == endDate == ""){
```

**correct**

```
if(byTitle === "" && byAuthor ==="" && startDate ==="" && endDate === ""){
```

Javascript has a simpler way to evaluate if a value is null, empty string or 0 by only evaluating the variable:

```
if(!byTitle  && !byAuthor && !startDate && !endDate ){
```

Another advise I wanted to share is to use "===" instead of "==".

Comment: You don't have to use `===` here instead of `==`. There's no reason you'd want to ensure those values are strings. Also your description of the chunk you took from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21134955/1317805) is incorrect. The `!` operator doesn't evaluate if a value is null, empty string, or 0, it converts the value to boolean then returns the opposite.

Comment: +1, never knew that `!byTitle` would also check for empty string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: The link above quotes Douglas Crockford saying "My advice is to never use the evil twins. Instead, always use === and !==. "

Comment: And for last your advice omitted that if the user types 0 it will evaluate as false when it is actually different than ""

Answer (score 3):

`""` is *[falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)*, so you can simply use:

```
if (!byTitle && !byAuthor && !startDate && !endDate) {
    ...
}
```

This uses [the logical NOT operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.9) on your variables (`!`) to convert them to boolean values, then return the opposite.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/p6nkt/).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can like this;

```
$(function(){
    var bytitle = $("input[name=byTitle]").val();
    var byAuthor = $("input[name=byAuthor]").val();
    var startDate = $("input[name=startDate]").val();
    var endDate = $("input[name=endDate]").val();

    if( bytitle == '' && byAuthor == '' && startDate == '' && endDate == '')
        alert("Enter at least one search parameter!");
});
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged in this question, nor is it mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AND](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/boolean.html) in your condition :

```
byTitle = "";
byAuthor = "";
startDate =""; 
endDate = ""
if(byTitle == "" && byAuthor =="" && startDate =="" && endDate == ""){
        alert("Enter at least one search parameter!");
        return false;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tCJ95/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ee = byTitle = byAuthor = startDate = endDate="";
if(ee=="null" || ee.length==0 || !ee)
{
    alert("all fields must be filled out");
    return false;
}
```